# Hilt 2.43 generates deprecation in app module

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

Using new hilt 2.43 got a warning in generated by hilt

```
warning: [deprecation] applicationContextModule(ApplicationContextModule) in Builder has been deprecated
          .applicationContextModule(new ApplicationContextModule(Hilt_App.this)).build();
```

Who can say how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same problem. I tried v2.44 and it appears to have it also!